# Matlab Matrixaddress

Tags: matlab, matrix, syntax, programming-languages, matrix-indexing

During my course I came across that expression:

```
A(:,end:-1:1)
```

> I have trouble to understand and read the morphemic structure of the 2nd Operand "end;-1;1"

---

Lets take the example:

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

I am aware of:

`A(:)`..   Outputs `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` as rows. Operator is `:`.
`A(1,:)`.. Outputs `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` as columns Operator is `,` then `,` .
`A(:,1)`.. Outputs `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` as rows. Operator is `,` beforehand `:` .

```
A(:,end:-1:1)
```

Output in Matlab show me: `3x3` Matrix.

How am I supposed to read the structure?

1. Graphem: : ..show me the rows,
2. Graphem: `end:-1` .. ??
3. Graphem: :`1` ..

Somehow "`:`" was for me the operator for show all of the elements.

It makes sense to me that the "`Operand1 , Operand2`" shows me the `2` Dimensional Matrix.

- First Idea:
  The `end:-1:1` expression seemed to me like a loop. So `-1, 0, 1 => **3x Elements**` ?
  But when I type

  `A(1,end:3)`
  it only shows me the 3rd row.
- Second Idea:

  `A(end:-1:1,1)`
  It shows me the inverted Matrix..

**My background**:
I am a undergraduate student from the field of language.
I build in my freetime the 8-Bit Sap1 according Ben Eater.
So I am familiar with program memory or instruction memory.
I [understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Understanding#Shallow_and_deep) only the result, but not how it is achieved by the MATLAB compiler.
Someone said to me that the "Matrixaddressing is somehow optimized".
Looking forward to a helpful answer in each step. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just read the docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Comment: The three examples you give under "I am aware of:" are all three wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `end` keyword in matrix indexing indicates index of last element in the corresponding dimension. So, `A(:,end:-1:1)` simply means `A(:, size(A, 2):-1:1)`, which in you example (`A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`), is equivalent to `A(:, 3:-1:1)`.

But to understand what it does, you need to know what `3:-1:1` does. It creates a subrange. You already know `1:3` creates `[1, 2, 3]`. `1:3` is simplified form of `1:1:3`: `rangeStrart:increment:rangeEnd`. Now, `3:1` or `3:1:1` creates an empty vector, because `rangeStart` is greater than `rangeEnd`. To create `[3, 2, 1]` you need to use a negative step: `3:-1:1`.

So, `A(:,end:-1:1)` means `A(:, [3, 2, 1])`, which inverts order of rows of `A`. Also, `A(:,end:3)` means `A(:, 3:3)` and eventually `A(:, 3)`, which returns 3rd row of `A`.

**Edit:** about your misunderstandings, addressed by @CrisLuengo

> I am aware of:
> A(:).. Outputs [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] as rows. Operator is :.
> A(1,:)..  Outputs [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] as columns Operator is , then , .
> A(:,1).. Outputs [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] as rows. Operator is ,beforehand : .

- `A(3, 2)` is the element in the 3,2 position (third row, second column) of A
- `A(1, :)` is equivalent to `A(1, 1:size(A, 2))` and `A(1, 1:end)` and is the first row of `A`
- `A(:, 1)` is equivalent to `A(1:size(A, 1), 1)` and `A(1:end, 1)` and is the first column of `A`
- `A(:)` is equivalent to `A(1:numel(A))` and is a single column containing all elements of `A`

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, when accessing an array, it is accessed as `A(row#,col#)`. `row#` and `col#` can either be integers or a vector of integers. If they are integers then one spot in the matrix is accessed. If they are vectors then MATLAB will loop through the vector and choose spots in `A` which correspond to the integers in the vector.

`end:-1:1` creates a vector which contains the integers ranging from the number of columns (in this case because you put this vector in the col section: `A(row#,col#)`) to 1. Ex: `4x5` matrix, `end:-1:1` would be `[5 4 3 2 1]`.

When you put : in the row part of the matrix, that means you access all rows of the matrix.

Here's an example of `A(:,end:-1:1)`

The `col#` vector (:) is `[1 2 3]` and the `row#` vector `(end:-1:1)` is `[3 2 1]`

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]

A(:,end:-1:1)

[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this slightly.
If we have a vector

```
A = [1 2 3]
```

and we call `A(end:-1:1)`, then we get  a vector `[3 2 1]`. The indexing has returned the same vector, with the values reversed. If we now have a matrix

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

and call `A(:, end:-1:1)`, we get the matrix with the same values in each row, but now the columns have been reversed to give

```
A(:, end:-1:1) = [3 2 1; 6 5 4; 9 8 7].
```

Recall what the colon means in this context.

If we define a vector, `v = (1:10)`, we get a vector with the first element being `1`, the last element being `10` and each value in between being integers in steps of `1`. If we instead define `v = (1:2:10)`, we get the same, but the elements are separated by `2`, not `1`.

`end:-1:1` is a vector made in just the same way. The first number is the final element in the row of `A`, and the final number is the first element in the row. Each number is separated by a value of `-1`. If we try

```
v = 10:-1:1
```

we get `[10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]`. If we call `v(2:4)` we get the second, third and fourth elements of `v`. If we call `v(1:end)`, we simply get `v`. If we call `v(end:-1:1)`, we return `v`, with the elements in the reversed order.

**Edit** A typo.